# Function expression with Arguments

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with function expressions and trying to get my head round some stuff.This is the code I wrote.

This works

```
var sum=function(arg1,arg2){
    return(function(){alert(arg1*arg2)})
}

document.getElementById('button_1').onclick=sum(3,2);
```

This doesnt,I know it doesnt even look right.But Im just trying to understand the reason behind the error that was being displayed here.It first displayed the alert box with 6 then an error message "Not Implemented",this is in IE6.

```
var sum=function(arg1,arg2){
    alert(arg1*arg2);
}

document.getElementById('button_1').onclick=sum(3,2);
```

If you guys think this question doesn't require an answer please let me know,I will delete it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example your sum variable doesn't return a function pointer. The `onclick` event must be assigned to a function pointer. So in this second example you are directly invoking the sum function by passing it two arguments and because this function doesn't return anything (it simply alerts) it doesn't work. To make it work with the second example you need:

```
document.getElementById('button_1').onclick = sum;
```

But once the button is clicked it will pass a single argument to this sum function which represents the event.

In the first example you invoke the sum function by passing it two arguments but this invocation simply returns another function which is then assigned to the onclick event.

I guess you want this though:

```
document.getElementById('button_1').onclick = function() { sum(3,2); };
```

Comment: @Darin if was to do to do this, document.getElementById('button_1').onclick=sum;, it alerts me with NaN.So do I have to return a function when I have to pass parameters for a function expression that is assiged to the onclick event?

Comment: @manraj82, if you use the onclick handler the only argument that will be passed will be the event. So if you want to assign some function to an onclick event this function can take only a single argument which is the event. You cannot assign functions which take multiple arguments, when the button is clicked javascript doesn't know what values to pass to this function.

Comment: @Darin So does that mean Im better off doing like this then <input type="button" id="button_1" onClick="sum(3,2)">

Comment: @manraj82, `onclick="sum(3,2)"` will work but if you want to do this unobtrusively I would recommend you the following: `document.getElementById('button_1').onclick = function() { sum(3,2); };`

Comment: @Darins thanks thats the answer I was looking for,Its clear to me now!!

Comment: @Darin whats this method called? I just want to do a bit more reading about this.I think I was using closures in the first example.

Comment: @manraj82, in your first example a closure is used to capture the outside `arg1` and `arg2` variables in the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

Using local variables is a preferred way as I have more control about *when* a function is called. Passing arguments to **function expressions** does not feel natural as it needs some strange syntax. Here is how I'm generally using functions in Javascript. 
Declare a locally scoped function: 
`var enableStopBtn = function('videoBtnId') {
   // do something
}`

Call the variable: 
`enableStopBtn('myVideob');`